# Cannot update Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, memory, windows-update

I have a x86 Windows 7 VM (using VirtualBox), and I am trying to update windows. The problem is I can't. Every time I try to update it I get the following error: 8007000E

So, to fix it, I added more memory to it, now it was 3GB of RAM. But that didn't fix it. I also found [this solution on a windows forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windowsupdate8007000e-windowsupdatedt000/ddb2b975-a767-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) which advised me to [run the troubleshooting app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/836941).

After doing that, I end up with another error, albeit a different one: 0x8024402C.

After investigation I ended up in another [windows forum discussion thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-updates-failing-with-error-code-0x8024402c/102d2851-3e28-423e-b425-4acfe156014e?auth=1) which led me into updating the [Windows Update Agent](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949104) (the updater needs an update ... ironic :D ).

But nothing works, and I am starting to get desperate. What am I missing? Why I can update my windows?

Comment: 0x8024402C = **WU_E_PT_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - Same as ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - the proxy server or target server name cannot be resolved.** You have network issues

Comment: Alright ! is there a website I can ping or something to be sure ?

Comment: ping superuser or google.

Answer (score 0):

I think Virtual Box is not compatible with the upgrade (as I've not used it, but I know quite a bit from it). Check your internet speed as well. Also, look for the minimum requirements for Windows 10 and set the VM settings to those requirements. If you want more flexibility you can switch to VMware for that. If you do a bit of googling and be a liitle smart, you can get the hard disk image running in VMware without reinstalling Windows 7 all over again.

Comment: I am just trying to run windows updates for 7, not trying a full upgrade to windows 10 :S

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Oops :P but you can try something from above. VMware also has some acceleration which might help you get the updates to the Microsoft software on your VM. The same applies above for your help, except the thing about the windows 10 minim. req. You can also google and search for the errors in Microsoft Help.